# What is the correct way to treat the primary key exception, when I can safely ignore it?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, exception

I need to enter some data fetched from the Hattrick website (online football manager) into a database, using C#. The database structure is the following:

```
MatchID (which is also primary key)
Rating1
Rating2
...
Rating16
```

All the fields are `TinyInt`.

Because the way the data are conceived, if I enter into the database a `MatchID` which is already present, I am 100% sure that the other fields Rating*x* will have the same value, so this exception can be safely ignored, so as not to bother the user.

To treat this exception, I used the following code:

```
string AddMatchCommand = "Insert into Games values (@Match, @Ratings1, @Ratings2, @Ratings3, @Ratings4, @Ratings5, @Ratings6, @Ratings7, @Ratings8, @Ratings9, @Ratings10, @Ratings11, @Ratings12, @Ratings13, @Ratings14, @Ratings15, @Ratings16)";
SqlConnection MyConn = new SqlConnection(CreateTableConnectionString);  
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(AddMatchCommand, MyConn);  

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Match", MatchIDToInsert.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));  
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ratings1", RatingsToInsert[0].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));  
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ratings2", RatingsToInsert[1].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));  
//...   
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ratings16", RatingsToInsert[15].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); 

MyConn.Open();  
try  
{  
 command.ExecuteNonQuery();  
}  
catch (SqlException S)  
{  
 if (S.Number != 2627)  //2627 is the ID for the exception I want to ignore
 {  
  MessageBox.Show(S.Message);  
 }  
}  
MyConn.Close();
```

The code above does its job. However, is there a better way to handle this situation? I am pretty sure that I may find a bug or two down the line, but I cannot prove this.

Comment: Look at the answer provided by @GordonLinoff but here's another tip. Your code is currently swallowing all SqlExceptions, even those that aren't duplicate keys. Yes, you are showing a message box, but perhaps it would be better to only catch and ignore the specific one you want? You can rewrite the catch clause like this: `catch (SqlException S) when (S.Number == 2627) { ... ignore ... }`

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen this is why I posted the `if (...)` clause. To ignore **only** the chosen exception.

Comment: As usual - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: @SMor Yes. I made the replacements between posting this question and waiting for your answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can phrase the query like this to avoid an error:

```
Insert into Games
    select @Match, @Ratings1, @Ratings2, @Ratings3, @Ratings4, @Ratings5, @Ratings6, @Ratings7, @Ratings8, @Ratings9, @Ratings10, @Ratings11, @Ratings12, @Ratings13, @Ratings14, @Ratings15, @Ratings16
    where not exists (select 1 from Games g where g.matchid = @match);
```

Comment: You don't need `from`, this isn't Oracle.

Comment: @RogerWolf . . . BigQuery, MariaDB and older versions of MySQL require a `from` to use `where` (although SQL Server, Postgres, SQLite, and MySQL 8+ do not).  I never remember which databases do and don't require it, so I'm inclined just to put it in.

Comment: @Steve . . . That is a viable solution as well.  The `INSERT` is simple enough that I see no reason to use `MERGE`.  Aaron Bertrand warns against `MERGE`, so I'm inclined to use alternative solutions (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks that link is very interesting. At this point I am inclined as well

Comment: @GordonLinoff very interesting insights you gave!